# how to setState in componentDidMount in promise without getting setState error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I'm calling an api and setting the state with the response. 
I'm not able to call setState without seeing this error: 
The error does not occur if setState happens outside the promise.

**How do you set an API response to state without seeing this error?**

> Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://localhost:8000/api/items'
    let items;
    fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

**Entire component for reference:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import GridList from '@material-ui/core/GridList';
import GridListTile from '@material-ui/core/GridListTile';
import GridListTileBar from '@material-ui/core/GridListTileBar';
import ListSubheader from '@material-ui/core/ListSubheader';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InfoIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Info';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
  icon: {
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)',
  },
});

class ItemList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }

    this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'https://localhost:8000/api/items'
    let items;
    fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'})
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  handleItemClick(id) {

  }

  handleRenderItems() {
      const { classes } = this.props
      const { items } = this.state;
      return this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
      const id = item.id;
      return (
        <GridListTile onClick={() => this.handleItemClick(id)} key={idx}>
        <img src={item.key_image} alt={item.title} />
        <GridListTileBar
          title={item.title}
          subtitle={<span>${item.rent_price_day}/day</span>}
          actionIcon={
            <IconButton className={classes.icon}>
              <InfoIcon />
            </IconButton>
          }
        />
        </GridListTile>
      )
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <GridList cols={3} cellHeight={220} className={classes.gridList}>
          <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={3} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
            <ListSubheader component="div">Popular Items</ListSubheader>
          </GridListTile>
          {this.handleRenderItems()}
        </GridList>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ItemList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ItemList);
```

Instead of handling this in the component - I think it may be simpler to handle the call to the API in an action creator, and use redux to store the data - then just send it to the component when it's available. Better to keep these details out of the view anyway.

Also, wouldn't typically use a style object in the view either - but it's boilerplate with material-ui.

Comment: Add a log line inside componentWillUnmount and check whether that log prints before you get this error.

Comment: Can you post the Component code?

Comment: It does. What conclusion can you draw from that?

Comment: @AdamAzad I'm using material-ui so there is quite a bit of boilerplate but I'll post it since you've asked.

Comment: That means your component is not there to set the state at the time, those promises get resolved. What makes parent component to unmount this component?

Comment: The solution is to not call `setState` on unmounted components.

Comment: @ArmanCharan It's considered idiomatic to call setState in componentDidMount - the nature of this lifecycle method is that it's called after render - so this error is a bit of a misnomer. There's some nuance here to avoid it when this logic is in the component. Curious what that is - though as mentioned - I think better practice is handling this in an action creator.

Comment: Your component looks fine. The error above, together with the fact that `componentWillUnmount` fires, suggests that your component is not mounted when `setState` is called @zero_cool

Comment: @ArmanCharan Interesting - that sounds plausible. It's just odd that the component is not mounted and componentDidMount is being run...

Answer (score 3):

Add below inside your component,

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this.isMounted = true;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.isMounted = false;
}
```

Then setState only if this.isMounted is true. This should solve your problem, **but this is not a recommended pattern**. Please refer https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html

Check the code of parent component which holds the `<ItemList/>`. If you are rendering `<ItemList/>` based on certain conditions, the problem might be in those conditions.

Comment: I was gonna mention what you did about it being somewhat of an anti-pattern. It may work but not ideal.

Comment: Can you post the code of the parent component which holds the <ItemList/> that might be helpful to determine the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It simple. You just have to return the value of the second promise in a variable.
Like this :

```
  let items; 
  let errorFetch;   
  fetch(url, {mode: 'cors'})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      items = result;
    },
    (error) => {
      errorFetch = error
    }
  );
  this.setState(items ? { isLoaded : true, items } : { isLoaded : true, error: errorFetch });
```

Comment: There's a little catch here with what values are available when the state gets set. Because of this - items === undefined instead of the value from the API, so this method will not work unfortunately. Using setTimeout may work, but I don't think it's necessary.